# How can I review and possibly alter all raw packets going through my system?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking

TL;DR

I can already **read** packets leaving and entering my system. I can also send raw packets. Now I want to, instead of just being able to **read**, have the power to change incoming/outgoing.

---

I have used the `AF_PACKET`, `SOCK_RAW` and `htons(ETH_P_ALL)` mix to be able to see all packets that leave or arrive at my system. I've also made a little program to print information about ethernet frame and underlying protocols (I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.3 64-bit using gcc 5.4.0):

```
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <netinet/ether.h>
#include <net/ethernet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "/home/bar/Libraries/Colors.h" //color macros (cdefault for default terminal color)
#include "/home/bar/Libraries/BitOperations.h" //Get8/Get16/Get32 (value, from, to)
#include "/home/bar/Libraries/EndianConversions.h" //ToLE16/ToLE32 (value)
#include "/home/bar/Libraries/PacketProtocolDefinitions.h" //network structs and defines (EthernetFrame/IpHeader/TCPHeader/UDP_HeaderLength/ICMP_Descriptors/etc..)

#define BuffLen 0x10000

char iface_count;
char** iface_list;


void workPackets(char* buffer, unsigned int BufferLen){
    struct EthernetFrame* ethernetFrame = (struct EthernetFrame*)buffer;

    char isMine = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < iface_count; ++i){
        if(!memcmp(iface_list[i], ethernetFrame->source, 6) || !memcmp(iface_list[i], ethernetFrame->destination, 6)){isMine = 1;break;}
    }
    printf("%s  Ethernet Frame: \n\
        Source Mac: %.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x\n\
        Destination Mac: %.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x\n\
        Ether Protocol: 0x%.4X\n"cdefault,
    isMine?magenta:green,
    ethernetFrame->source[0], ethernetFrame->source[1], ethernetFrame->source[2], ethernetFrame->source[3], ethernetFrame->source[4], ethernetFrame->source[5], 
    ethernetFrame->destination[0], ethernetFrame->destination[1], ethernetFrame->destination[2], ethernetFrame->destination[3], ethernetFrame->destination[4], ethernetFrame->destination[5],
    ToLE16(ethernetFrame->ethertype));



    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////-------------------IP---------------//////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (ToLE16(ethernetFrame->ethertype) == ethertype_IP)
    {
        struct IpHeader* ipheader = (struct IpHeader*)(buffer+14);
        printf(cyan"    IP header:\n\
        Source IP: %d.%d.%d.%d\n\
        Destination IP: %d.%d.%d.%d\n\
        Total Size: 0x%X\n\
        Protocol: 0x%X\n"cdefault,
        ipheader->source[0], ipheader->source[1], ipheader->source[2], ipheader->source[3],
        ipheader->destination[0], ipheader->destination[1], ipheader->destination[2], ipheader->destination[3],
        ToLE16(ipheader->TotalLength), ipheader->Protocol);



        //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<//
        //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<-------------TCP----------<<<<<<<<<<<<<//
        //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<//
        if(ipheader->Protocol == IP_PROTO_TCP){
            struct TCPHeader* tcpheader = (struct TCPHeader*)((void*)ipheader+(ipheader->Version__IHL&0xF)*4);
            printf(cyan"    TCP header:\n\
        Source Port: %u\n\
        Destination Port: %u\n\
        Flags:\n\
            SYN: %s\n\
            ACK: %s\n\
            FIN: %s\n\
        Data Offset: 0x%X\n\
        Sequence Number: %u\n"cdefault,
            tcpheader->source_port, tcpheader->destination_port,
            tcpheader->flags.SYN?"SET":"Zero", 
            tcpheader->flags.ACK?"SET":"Zero",
            tcpheader->flags.FIN?"SET":"Zero",
            Get8(tcpheader->data_offset__NS, 0, 4), tcpheader->sequence_number);
            char* toPrint = (char*)tcpheader;
            unsigned short packet_size = ToLE16(ipheader->TotalLength) - Get8(ipheader->Version__IHL, 4, 8)*4 - Get8(tcpheader->data_offset__NS, 0, 4)*4;
            printf("data(packet size:0x%.2X): %*.*s", packet_size, packet_size, packet_size, toPrint + Get8(tcpheader->data_offset__NS, 0, 4)*4);



        //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<//
        //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<-------------UDP----------<<<<<<<<<<<<<//
        //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<//
        }else if (ipheader->Protocol == IP_PROTO_UDP){
            struct UDPHeader* udpheader = (struct UDPHeader*)((void*)ipheader+(ipheader->Version__IHL&0xF)*4);
            printf(cyan"    UDP header:\n\
        Source Port: %u\n\
        Destination Port: %u\n\
        Length: 0x%X\n"cdefault,
            ToLE16(udpheader->source_port), ToLE16(udpheader->destination_port), ToLE16(udpheader->length));
            void* toPrint = (void*)udpheader;
            unsigned short packet_size = ToLE16(udpheader->length) - UDP_HeaderLength;
            printf("data(packet size:0x%.2X) %p: %*.*s",packet_size, toPrint, packet_size, packet_size, (char*)toPrint+UDP_HeaderLength);



        //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<//
        //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<------------ICMP----------<<<<<<<<<<<<<//
        //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<//
        }else if(ipheader->Protocol == IP_PROTO_ICMP){
            struct ICMPHeader* icmpheader = (struct ICMPHeader*)((void*)ipheader+(ipheader->Version__IHL&0xF)*4);
            printf(red" ICMP packet: %s\n"cdefault, ICMP_Descriptors[icmpheader->type][icmpheader->code]);
        }



    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////------------------ARP---------------//////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }else if (ToLE16(ethernetFrame->ethertype) == ethertype_ARP){
        struct ARPframe* arpframe = (struct ARPframe*)(buffer+14);
        printf(yellow"  ARP %s:\n\
        Sender Mac: %.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X\n\
        Sender IP: %d.%d.%d.%d\n\
        Target IP: %d.%d.%d.%d\n\
        Target Mac: %.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X\n"cdefault,
        ToLE16(arpframe->Operation)==2?"reply":"request",
        arpframe->SenderMac[0], arpframe->SenderMac[1], arpframe->SenderMac[2], arpframe->SenderMac[3], arpframe->SenderMac[4], arpframe->SenderMac[5],
        arpframe->SenderIP[0], arpframe->SenderIP[1], arpframe->SenderIP[2], arpframe->SenderIP[3],
        arpframe->TargetIP[0], arpframe->TargetIP[1], arpframe->TargetIP[2], arpframe->TargetIP[3],
        arpframe->TargetMac[0], arpframe->TargetMac[1], arpframe->TargetMac[2], arpframe->TargetMac[3], arpframe->TargetMac[4], arpframe->TargetMac[5]);



    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////-----------------SIZE---------------//////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }else if (ToLE16(ethernetFrame->ethertype) <= 0x5DC){
        if(!memcmp(ethernetFrame->source, MAC_STPorLLDP, 6)||!memcmp(ethernetFrame->destination, MAC_STPorLLDP, 6)){
            if(ethernetFrame->ethertype != ethertype_LLDP){
                printf(blue"    STP Packet\n");
            }else{
                printf(blue"    LLDP Packet\n");
            }
        }else{
            printf(red" Unknown Packet Type: Provided Packet Size 0x%.4X:\n     ", ToLE16(ethernetFrame->ethertype));
            for (int i = 0; i < BufferLen; ++i)
            {
                printf("%.2X ", buffer[i]&0xFF);
                if(!((i+1)%6)){
                    printf("\n      ");
                }
            }
        }
        printf(cdefault);



    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////-----------------IPv6---------------//////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }else if(ToLE16(ethernetFrame->ethertype) == ethertype_IPv6){
        printf(blue"    IPv6 Packet\n"cdefault);
    }
    return;
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int sock_r;
    unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char *) malloc(BuffLen); //to receive data
    memset(buffer,0,BuffLen);
    struct sockaddr saddr;
    int saddr_len = sizeof (saddr), buflen;




//--------------------------------------------Get My Macs

    struct ifaddrs *ifap, *ifaptr;
    unsigned char *ptr;

    if (getifaddrs(&ifap) == 0) {
        for(ifaptr = ifap; ifaptr != NULL; ifaptr = (ifaptr)->ifa_next) 
            if(ifaptr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_PACKET)
                iface_count++;
        iface_list = malloc(iface_count*sizeof(void*));
        char tempcount = 0;
        for(ifaptr = ifap; ifaptr != NULL; ifaptr = (ifaptr)->ifa_next) {
            if(ifaptr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_PACKET){
                iface_list[tempcount] = malloc(6);
                memcpy(iface_list[tempcount++], &(ifaptr->ifa_addr->sa_data[10]), 6);
            }
        }
        freeifaddrs(ifap);
    } else {
        perror("Getifaddrs");
    }

    printf("My interfaces: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < iface_count; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d: %.2X %.2X %.2X %.2X %.2X %.2X\n", i, 
            iface_list[i][0] & 0xFF, iface_list[i][1] & 0xFF, iface_list[i][2] & 0xFF, 
            iface_list[i][3] & 0xFF, iface_list[i][4] & 0xFF, iface_list[i][5] & 0xFF);
    }

//----------------------------------------------

    sock_r = socket(AF_PACKET,SOCK_RAW,htons(ETH_P_ALL));
    if(sock_r<0)
    {
        perror("SOCKET");
        return -1;
    }printf("socket connected successfully");


    while(1){
        //Receive a network packet and copy in to buffer
        printf("\n//-----------------------//-----------------------//\n");
        buflen=recvfrom(sock_r,buffer,BuffLen,0,&saddr,(socklen_t *)&saddr_len);
        if(buflen<0)
        {
            perror("Receiving");
            return -1;
        }
        workPackets(buffer, buflen);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < iface_count; ++i){free(iface_list[i]);}
    free(iface_list);

    return 0;
}
```

Along with this I have the ability to send spoofed packets with any information I desire, by just building those from the ground up.

That's all good, but now I want to be able to review and possibly change all packets coming in and out of my system.

What I mean by this is:
If I for example wanted to be edgy and spoof my mac to `13:37:AF:CO:DE:B8`(not sure if that's even valid), I could just find mine in the ethernet frame and change it going out, and do the opposite when coming in.

This would give me a lot of flexibility, if I for example wanted to keep my original MAC/IP for TCP and UDP, but have it spoofed for ARP.
Would be cool to fake being 2 or more different systems at the same time, or even, if doing MiTM, route the traffic through manually while being able to do anything else I want.

Now I've been searching for a bit, and what I've found was [netfilter_queue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/143745/preprocess-packets-send-to-from-interface), that seems to be [deprecated](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/doxygen/group__Queue.html).
I've also found a [kernel netfilter](https://kel.bz/post/netfilter/), but if possible I would like to avoid kernel stuff, since I've started using linux only recently and that seems like a pretty big step to take.

In windows there were these system-wide hooks for events like input, which were really intuitive and easy to use, and I was just looking for an equivalent.

Note: I'm doing all this for learning purposes, I do not want to use libraries or frameworks.

So my question is: Is there a valid non-kernel way to scoop up and change  packets?

Feel free to request any information you may need or criticize me if you consider I've done something wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: You can do this with [netmap](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/netmap/).  It lets you insert user-level code between the network stack and a NIC driver.  You get a transmit and receive FIFO to the NIC, and a transmit and receive FIFO to the stack.  Packets that arrive from the NIC can be modified and passed to the stack, and packets that arrive from the stack can be modified and passed to the NIC.

Comment: Well, if you can promiscuously read, and you can spoof, then you just need to get physically in the way.  Think of it as pretending to be a wire.

Comment: Oh, on second read you mean traffic to/from your own applications on the same machine as the filter.  Disregard my other comment.

Comment: @pat I requested a solution that didn't involve using libraries or frameworks not native to linux. I've now gone into kernel stuff, and found that not even with a netfilter hook can I achieve what I want in terms of packet sending, since the ethernet header is not provided in the hook, and is only generated forward in the process.

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer to this since my country just outright banned UDP. I would really like to have a fix for it.

Comment: Have a look at the non-deprecated APIs for [`netfilter_queue`](https://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/doxygen/html/modules.html), specifically the last three entries on the list. [This example](https://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/doxygen/html/nf-queue_8c_source.html) could also help

Comment: @AlexApps99 I think this answers the question. Thank you so much. Please make it an answer so I can give you the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the non-deprecated APIs for [`netfilter_queue`](https://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/doxygen/html/modules.html), specifically the last three entries on the list (Verdict helpers, Config helpers, Netlink message helper functions). [This example](https://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/doxygen/html/nf-queue_8c_source.html) could also help.